# Order of execution of the absolute earliest places to run code in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, lifecycle

There are numerous places you can have initialization code be executed in ASP.NET:

- web.config is processed
- WebActivator `PreApplicationStartMethod`
- WebActivator `PostApplicationStartMethod`
- Global.asax  `Application_Start`

What is the ordering of these occurences? Are there any other additional items that should be to this list?

**Edit:** Since it was mentioned that statics are relevant to first invocation location, I'm going to break this up for them

Foo class that is used in a WebActivator `PreApplicationStartMethod`

- static constructor
- static readonly field

Bar class that is used in a WebActivator `PostApplicationStartMethod`

- static constructor
- static readonly field

Baz class that is used in a Global.asax  `Application_Start`

- static constructor
- static readonly field

For clarity purposes, suppose that in the above examples each of those depends on the Foo/Bar/Baz class being used in the location and that the class contains  a static constructor and static readonly field.

Comment: Have you look at [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview ??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you interested in application start up or the page life cycle?

Comment: @jrummell ASP.NET application start up, not page life cycle there's tons of information regarding page life cycle. My list has nothing relevant to page specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Static constructors and static field initialization is determined by the runtime, not ASP.NET. Eric Lippert recently posted a great [four](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/)-[part](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/11/static-constructors-part-two/) [blog](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/14/static-constructors-part-three/) [series](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/18/static-constructors-part-four/) detailing how they work.

As for the rest of the items you mentioned, methods marked with the [`System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx) are executed first. According to the MSDN documentation for this attribute, there is no guarantee of the order in which these methods are called.

According to [a blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx) by Phil Haack, this attribute gives developers the opportunity to call two other methods during the application's startup: [`BuildProvider.RegisterBuildProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildprovider.registerbuildprovider.aspx) and [`BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.addreferencedassembly.aspx). The MSDN documentation for `BuildManager.AddReferenceAssembly` states that this method can only be executed during the Application_PreStartInit stage of the application, which suggests that's when all methods marked by the `System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` are executed.

WebActivator uses the framework's `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` to hook into the application's startup. Once called, it will search for and execute all methods marked by the `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` before it dynamically registers [an HttpModule](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator/blob/master/WebActivator/ActivationManager.cs#L131) that will later invoke all methods marked by the `PostApplicationStartMethodAttribute` - after Application_Start has been called in the HttpApplication class.

So, to summarize, the order is:

1. Web.config is read into memory
2. Methods marked with a `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`
3. HttpApplication.Application_Start
4. Methods marked with `WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethodAttribute`

Comment: So the web.config should actually be viewed as step 0 in your list? Also can you provide a source to "during the PreStartInit stage of the application. There is no guarantee of the order in which these methods are called."

Comment: @ChrisMarisic The MSDN documentation for the `System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` states that there is no guaranteed order of execution for methods marked by it.

Answer (score 2):

The application life cycle looks like this:

- A request is made for an application resource.
- The unified pipeline receives the first request for the application.
- Response objects are created for each request.
- An HttpApplication object is assigned to the request
- The request is processed by the [HttpApplication pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Additionally, here are the events that occur in the request pipeline:

[image: ASP.NET Application Life Cycle]

See [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

Static constructors and static readonly fields (instantiated inline) are initialized the first time that type is used by your code. That could happen any point in the application lifetime.

**Specifically answering your question**

According to the [WebActivator project page](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator#choosing-when-your-code-executes), this is the order of events:

1. web.config is processed
2. WebActivator PreApplicationStartMethod
3. Global.asax Application_Start
4. WebActivator PostApplicationStartMethod

As far as static initialization goes, see [Eric Lipperts posts](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/) that Justin linked in his answer.

Comment: That image is much later in the timeline than I'm talking about, also no one has even directly spoke about webactivator or web.config processing

Answer (score 0):

Your current list has some things that aren't necessarily related to ASP.NET only (static readonly fields, etc.), but [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) describes the ASP.NET lifecycle. There are a ton of things that happen, many of them allow customization where you could inject some of your own code if you had good reason to.

Your question is pretty broad. Is there something you're trying to accomplish here that could hope hone in on what part of the process would be ideal for what you want to do?